# OSB Invocation of business service resulted in an error

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-service-bus

I haven't work with OSB and Oracle products at all, but the time has come and i get some task at my job to configure weblogic server and setup backup of old osb server.

I've installed weblogic and import that backup. Proxy services seems ok, but all business services broken. When i try to test them with test console in sbconsole, i get some weird error.

Error says that: The invocation resulted in an error: While trying to lookup 'jms.TestBusinessService' didn't find subcontext 'jms'. Resolved ''.

Business service url is 'jms://localhost:7001/weblogic.jms.XAConnectionFactory/jms.TestBusinessService'.

It seems that server dont know how to call service and he wants valid address. How can I setup connection to 'jms.TestBusinessService' in Connection Factory?

Comment: Have you created the JMS on Weblogic server?

Comment: I have found old JMS settings and succeessfully applied them to new weblogic server. I find that out about month ago.

Answer (score 2):

There should be configuration of server included in the backup. Setup and settings for all the resources used. Error states that business service can't invoke (pass the message to) the resource on the new service, missing obviously.

There is no documentation on jms infrastructure (that is used by projects) included in backup, right? Preferably some kind of automated solution - Python script for setting all up via wlst, etc?

If not - is the original server still available? You could manually check jms resources and copy those.

No again? You'll have to go to weblogic console and manually create jms connection factory(ies) and queue(s)/topic(s) that are referenced by business services. Gl hf - fine-tuning parameters of those will be really fun.

Answer (score 0):

It means that at least proper JMS queue definition is missing.

Go to http://localhost:7001/console and check if JMS is cofigured:

- Services -> Messaging -> JMS Servers
- Services -> Messaging -> JMS Modules (when it exists, here, in one of modules, you should find expected queue)

[Here you can find documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E92727_01/techwebhelp/Content/techdocs/technicaldocs/jmsmultientity/jmstep2.htm) saying how to configure simple JMS queue in Oracle Weblogic.

[Alternative instruction](https://www.techsupper.com/2017/02/jms-queue-in-weblogic-server-12c/).